# use PlantUML diagram code in PHP/Phabricator

Tags: php, uml, phabricator, plantuml

Looking for advice from developers phamiliar with PHP, or [Phabricator](https://secure.phabricator.com/) internals,
on how to make [Phabricator](https://github.com/phacility/phabricator) to have [PlantUML (text to UML diagrams)](https://plantuml.com/) within wiki pages, tasks. So that this UML code snippet in GitHub/[GitLab grammar](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/integration/plantuml.html)

````
```plantuml

Bob->Alice : hello

```
````

would be shown as diagram on rendered wiki page.

[image: sequence diagram generated example]

"Call it from PHP" page on https://plantuml.com/demophp.php is `404 - Not Found`.

UPDATE Please add answer with any further improvements or suggestions.

Comment: did you look at [tools using plantuml](https://plantuml.com/en/running) to have examples of integration ? Also [PHP API Client Code](https://plantuml.com/fr/code-php) (referenced in https://plantuml.com/fr/sitemap-plugins)

Comment: Thanks I did, calling a server with https://github.com/jawira/plantuml-encoding shown as example is not intention. We can deploy plantuml.jar to the Phabricator, the issue will be how to intregrate it's (local) usage within Phabricator code.

Comment: Mediawiki (Wikipedia source, in PHP) has an [extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PlantUML) for PlantUML. Would something like [this code](https://github.com/pjkersten/PlantUML/blob/576f910c1a89b1506bbcb0aa4188a0a76bc9c9cf/PlantUML.body.php#L266) work for you?

Answer (score 3):

The syntax you have used is for syntax highlighting of source code.  I think it would be better to define a new remarkup tag for this purpose (by extending `PhabricatorRemarkupCustomBlockRule` in a custom extension) rather than trying to overload syntax highlighting.

Unfortunately I can't find any examples of extending `PhabricatorRemarkupCustomBlockRule`, but there are examples of extending `PhabricatorRemarkupCustomInlineRule` which should be similar, such as here: https://discourse.phabricator-community.org/t/hyperlink-to-external-bug-tracking-system/1415

Comment: Thank you, that is the start.  Yes, it is exactly how to write within markdown to get picture instead of just highlight. See for example GitLab https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/integration/plantuml.html